# Handling specialKeys with HotKeys plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, hotkeys, keycode

I'm trying to get https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys to work, but:

```
$('#myInput').on({
    'keydown.space keydown.left keydown.right keydown.- keydown..' : function(e)
    {
        console.log( e.which );
    }
});
```

The above snippet responds to <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd> buttons. No hyphen and neither of dots (the one near <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and the numpad one) invoke the event.

And, hence, the question,

**How do I target special keys like dot + numpad dot, numpad add + plus, numpad subtract + hyphen, quote, colon etc.?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys/issues/3) and [this](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys/issues/7), keypress doesn't fire on special characters in the version of 'hotkeys' that you are using.  I'd recommend switching to [this](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) similar library that was actually a fork of the tzuryby library and written by John Resig.

You can capture the period key like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMKLR/).

Comment: Oh, I saw that the tzuryby's version was more recently updated, and thought that Johns one is obsolete. Anyways, I ended up working with Mousetrap (http://craig.is/killing/mice).

Answer (score 1):

To use a period with hotkeys, I added `190: "period"` to `specialKeys` in `jquery.hotkeys.js` Then I can use "period" for the keydown event. I'm assuming the same would work for a hyphen.